# matlab for each element small operation

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a small problem:

I have a matrix *A* like [1 2;4 1]

and a vector *ref* like [0 1 0 1 1 0 1 2]

the value of Matrix *A* is the index of *ref*.

In the end i want this solution [0 1;1 0]
(in Matrix *A* at position (1,1) is 1, so in the solution at position (1,1) should be the value of *ref* at position 1, and so on)

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simple indexing:

```
>> ref(A)

ans = 

  0   1
  1   0
```

Comment: @user2441536: Well, you haven't shown your code, so neither do I!  You should create a simple test-case, and then add that to your question.

Comment: I have a 900x900 matrix, typ double oder uint8 or whatever, with only positive Integers in it... what could be the problem